# Hide table information when using graphs in DynamicReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I'm using DynamicReports.  On their website  http://dynamicreports.sourceforge.net/examples/examples.html I only see graph examples where both the table information and the graph appear.

I only need the graph portion. I'm trying to figure out how to hide the table part of the report.

Anyone knows how to hide the table portion when viewing graphs?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this example the table doesn't appear

http://www.dynamicreports.org/examples/multiaxischartreport.html

Try to do the same, and change the chart.

```
report().setTemplate(Templates.reportTemplate)
        .fields(dateField)  
        .title(  
            Templates.createTitleComponent("MultiAxisChart"),  
            cht.multiAxisChart(chart1, chart2),  
            cht.multiAxisChart()  
                .addChart(chart1, AxisPosition.LEFT_OR_TOP)  
                .addChart(chart2, AxisPosition.RIGHT_OR_BOTTOM))  
          .pageFooter(Templates.footerComponent)  
          .setDataSource(createDataSource())  
          .show();
```